# object property's null value converted to "null" string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have an Angular app that is sending an object via a PUT request to my Express server. The content-type of my request is multipart/form-data.

The object is like this:

```
obj = {
   field1 : "foo",
   field2 : null
}
```

Once the request received by my Express server for processing, the value `null` gets converted to the string "null".
In other words `req.body.field2` is equal to a string...

How can I make sure that I preserve the null value on incoming requests?

Maybe body-parser is stringifying the null values ?

**UPDATE:**
This is the payload of my request as seen in chrome devtools. The null values in the payload aren't strings.

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryvjzQW5NA0dVuzUST
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="artist_id"

bananana
------WebKitFormBoundaryvjzQW5NA0dVuzUST
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="album"

pomme
------WebKitFormBoundaryvjzQW5NA0dVuzUST
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="year"

cerise
------WebKitFormBoundaryvjzQW5NA0dVuzUST
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="front_cover"

null
------WebKitFormBoundaryvjzQW5NA0dVuzUST
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="back_cover"

null
------WebKitFormBoundaryvjzQW5NA0dVuzUST--
```

Comment: You could force the bodyParser to use JSON only.  bodyParser.json(options).  Also are you sure your sending JSON, in say chrome inspector what does it say?

Comment: updated my post. It looks like null values are sent.

Comment: Post the Angular code that's making the request.

Answer (score 0):

Try using colons `:` instead of `=`

```
obj = {
   field1 : "foo",
   field2 : null
}
```